# Pandas subtract datetime condition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I would like to loop through a dataframe and subtract datetimes only if the ID matches in each row. As the example below shows however, my for loop is not working. All the NAN values are still in there, and I get the warning below. I have tried many variations and do not understand the problem.

I have also given code below for the desired output dataframe. After I fix this, I would like to condition based on the Days_since column and assign values to Chg_avg_value based on the  following condition: If the Days_since entry equals NAN, then Chg_avg_value equals NAN; else, subtract Avg. Value entries.

Thank you very much. I am really struggling with the pandas indexing.

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

Initial Dataframe:

```
df_so_dict={'Index':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'DateOf': ['2017-08-01','2017-08-03','2017-08-04', '2017-08-07','2017-08-09','2017-08-11','2017-08-12','2017-08-02','2017-08-04','2017-08-07'],
    'ID': ['553','553','553','559','559','559','559','914','914','914'], 'Count': [4,1,3,4,9,11,4,2,10,5],
    'Avg. Value': [4.4,3,5.3,6.4,5,4.2,3.5,2,3.3,2.2]
    }
df_so_ex2=pd.DataFrame(df_so_dict)
df_so_ex2.set_index('Index',inplace=True)
df_so_ex2['DateOf'] = pd.to_datetime(df_so_ex2['DateOf'])
df_so_ex2.dtypes #ID is an object
```

Loop:

```
new=1
prev=0
df_so_ex['Days_since']=np.nan

    if df_so_ex.iloc[new]['ID'] == df_so_ex.iloc[prev]['ID']:
        df_so_ex.iloc[new]['Days_since']=df_so_ex.iloc[new]['DateOf'] - df_so_ex.iloc[prev]['DateOf']
        new+=1
        prev+=1
    else:
        new+=1
        prev+=1
    print(new)
    print(prev)
```

Desired Dataframe:

```
df_so_dict_ans={'Index':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'DateOf': ['2017-08-01','2017-08-03','2017-08-04', '2017-08-07','2017-08-09','2017-08-11','2017-08-12','2017-08-02','2017-08-04','2017-08-07'],
    'ID': ['553','553','553','559','559','559','559','914','914','914'], 'Count': [4,1,3,4,9,11,4,2,10,5],
    'Avg. Value': [4.4,3,5.3,6.4,5,4.2,3.5,2,3.3,2.2],
    'Days_since':['nan',2,1,'nan',2,2,1,'nan',2,3],
    'Chg_avg_value':['nan',-1.4,2.3,'nan',-1.4,-0.8,-0.7,'nan',1.3,-1.1]
    }

df_so_ex_ans=pd.DataFrame(df_so_dict_ans)
df_so_ex_ans.set_index('Index',inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `groupby` + `pd.Series.diff`:

```
g = df_so_ex2.groupby('ID')

df_so_ex2['Chg_avg_value'] = g['Avg. Value'].apply(pd.Series.diff)
df_so_ex2['Days_since'] = g['DateOf'].apply(pd.Series.diff).dt.days

print(df_so_ex2)

       Avg. Value  Count     DateOf   ID  Chg_avg_value  Days_since
Index                                                              
0             4.4      4 2017-08-01  553            NaN         NaN
1             3.0      1 2017-08-03  553           -1.4         2.0
2             5.3      3 2017-08-04  553            2.3         1.0
3             6.4      4 2017-08-07  559            NaN         NaN
4             5.0      9 2017-08-09  559           -1.4         2.0
5             4.2     11 2017-08-11  559           -0.8         2.0
6             3.5      4 2017-08-12  559           -0.7         1.0
7             2.0      2 2017-08-02  914            NaN         NaN
8             3.3     10 2017-08-04  914            1.3         2.0
9             2.2      5 2017-08-07  914           -1.1         3.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is much better than the for loop. The use of series here is smart, as is using the group for the change in value

Answer (score 2):

You can using `groupby` `diff` , after you get the result , `concat` it back

```
s=df_so_ex2.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x : pd.DataFrame({'Days_since':x['DateOf'].diff().dt.days,'Chg_avg_value':x['Avg. Value'].diff()}))
pd.concat([df_so_ex2,s],axis = 1)
Out[460]: 
       Avg. Value  Count     DateOf   ID  Chg_avg_value  Days_since
Index                                                              
0             4.4      4 2017-08-01  553            NaN         NaN
1             3.0      1 2017-08-03  553           -1.4         2.0
2             5.3      3 2017-08-04  553            2.3         1.0
3             6.4      4 2017-08-07  559            NaN         NaN
4             5.0      9 2017-08-09  559           -1.4         2.0
5             4.2     11 2017-08-11  559           -0.8         2.0
6             3.5      4 2017-08-12  559           -0.7         1.0
7             2.0      2 2017-08-02  914            NaN         NaN
8             3.3     10 2017-08-04  914            1.3         2.0
9             2.2      5 2017-08-07  914           -1.1         3.0
```